# java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Tags: java, windows, linux, browser, applet

```
File posisifileXML = new File("namefile.xml");
Writer outXML = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(posisifileXML));
outXML.write(String1);
outXML.close();
```

I have created Java applet in Linux, the program is used to create a `namefile.xml`, when I'm accessing java applet from the browser (with that Linux) to create a file, it's worked.  That file is saved in my home directory.  But the problem is when I'm accessing that Java applet from the browser with another computer (Windows 7), then appeared an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:namefile.xml (Access is denied)
```

oh sorry, I want to create a file from client's computer (windows 7) to the server's computer via the client's browser (using java applet)..

What should I do?

Comment: will you please write complete stack trace of exception ?

Comment: I think on the client computer you donot have right to create the file. May be you can try giving full permissions to the user for a folder(on the Windows 7 machine) and try to create the file there.. thus you can confirm if its a access denial issue. Alternatively you can also try to read an existing file on the client machine. If read fails then you can confirm that its an issue due of access rights...

Comment: thanks for your response..
the problem is resolved, in client's computer (using windows 7) has different command what i have wrote in java applet in server's computer (ubuntu). that is why worked in ubuntu  but did't work in windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You should have posted the code :(

However, I have had the same issue because of the following two issues, when I was working with Applets

1. The access was restricted by windows (sometimes user privileges can do it. i.e: in my machine, it's hard to access C:/Desktop for programs)
2. Forgot to give the rights using Policy tool
3. The program is seeking for an existing file, but there is no such

Comment: thanks for your response.. 
I can access database from my windows to that linux using browser, because i have used keytool instead policy tool..

Answer (score 0):

```
File posisifileXML = new File("namefile.xml");
```

Never dump a `File` from an applet into the 'default directory'.  Make that something like:

```
File posisifileXML = new File(
    new File(System.getProperty("user.home")), 
    "namefile.xml");
```

---

> I want to create a file from client's computer (windows 7) to the server's computer via the client's browser..

An applet on the client computer can not create or access a `File` on the server, security aside.  File objects just do not work that way.

In order to get information from the user to be saved on the server file-system, requires help from the server.

Comment: oh sorry, I want to create a file from client's computer (windows 7) to the server's computer (ubuntu) via the client's browser (using java applet)..

Comment: See the update.  So far you have done a very poor job of explaining the problem.